# c legacy code gives me pointer on left; needs integral value on right error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

i try to compile lagecy code in visual studio 2013 
in some part of the code i have this section which gives me compilation error which i dont understand :

```
{

    const char* str ="111";
        const char* str1 = "TTTTTT";
        str -= str1;
...
...
}

 \example\example.c(170): error C2297: '-=' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char *'
 \example\example.c(170): error C2114: '-=' : pointer on left; needs integral value on right
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: This code is invalid in C and C++. What do you expect the result should be?

Comment: What is the result which you want?

Comment: Effectively, that's the same as `str = str - str1;` Pointer subtraction is only valid if the two pointers are pointing to elements within (or just past the last element) of the same array. The result is an integer (of type `ptrdiff_t`) and you're trying to convert the integer back to a pointer without a cast. Not that the code makes much sense anyway! `str -= str1` is even more illegal than `str = str - str1` and is not allowed at all by the C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks terrible. It's not valid C or C++. We can only guess what it meant to do. Perhaps you could replace the last line with the following:

```
str = (void*)(str - str1);
```

but there's no guarantee it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error description is quite self-explanatory. You can't have `const char*` on the right if you've got pointer on the left. Such arithmetics are only possible using integers.